# Custom TOC template for Markdown-to-ePub using Pandoc

Tags: epub, pandoc

I'm converting Markdown files to ePub using Pandoc.
I'm able to customize the auto-generated title page by using the `--template` option.

Now I'm trying to do the same with the auto-generated table of contents.
Is this possible?

I'm able to apply styles to it by using the `#toc-title` identifier.
But I also need to add custom content to the TOC page.
How do I do that with Pandoc?

Help please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been able to solve this either. Instead I'm creating a custom Table of Contents page  and using internal links to populate the TOC: http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#internal-links